# Conditional variance of simple random walk

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables, conditional-expectation, variance

Let $\{X_i \mid i \in \mathbb{N} \}$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with probability mass function given by:

$$
P(X_i = x)=
\begin{cases}
p, & \text{if } x = -1\\
1-p, & \text{if } x = 1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

For $t>0$, define $S_t = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^t X_i$ and $S_0 = 0$. I would like to find $\operatorname{Var} (S_t \mid S_s)$, where $0\le s <t$. Is there some property of the conditional variance that I am missing here? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First note that $\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = 4p(1-p).$

Since these are independent, you have $\operatorname{Var} S_t = t \operatorname{Var}(X_i) = 4tp(1-p).$

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(S_t\mid S_s) & = \operatorname{Var}\left( S_s + X_{s+1}+X_{s+2} + X_{s+3} + \cdots + X_t \mid S_s \right) \\[10pt]
& = \operatorname{Var}\left(X_{s+1}+X_{s+2} + X_{s+3} + \cdots + X_t \right).
\end{align}
This last equality holds because when you condition on $S_s$ you treat $S_s$ as a constant.  Adding a constant to a random variable does not change its variance.  And we don't need to say $\operatorname{Var}(X_{s+1}+X_{s+2} + X_{s+3} + \cdots + X_t\mid S_s)$ because $X_{s+1}, X_{s+2}, X_{s+3}, \ldots, X_t$ are independent of $S_s$.

So you get $(t-s)4p(1-p).$

Comment: This is perfectly clear! What if I want $E(Var(S_t \ | \ S_s)$? Will I proceed in the same fashion and conclude that this expectation is simply $(t−s)4p(1−p)$?

Comment: In generaly the expected value of the conditional variance is non-trivial, but in this case it is trivial because the conditional variance given $S_s$ does not depend on $S_s$; it is constant, i.e. not random.  The expected value of a constant is itself. $\qquad$